# Meaning of "Lucero" - Isaiah 14:12 vs 2 Peter 1:19

Tags: hebrew, spanish

Some time ago, I was reading Isaiah 14:12 in the KJV.
And then I checked my RV1960 with the same verse.
And I found that it says "Lucero"

> 12 !Cómo caíste del cielo, oh Lucero, hijo de la mañana! Cortado fuiste por tierra, tú que debilitabas a las naciones.

And then in the same Bible says in 2 Peter 1:19

> 19 Tenemos también la palabra profética más segura, a la cual hacéis bien en estar atentos como a una antorcha que alumbra en lugar oscuro, hasta que el día esclarezca y el lucero de la mañana salga en vuestros corazones;

You see, Isaiah 14:12 tells us in Spanish that the enemy is "Lucero" and in 2 Peter 1:19 says that Christ is the "Lucero". But the text in Hebrew, in Spanish, and in English says in Isaiah 14:12 "Lucifer". Can you tell me if there is a Bible in Spanish that has the correct translation from Hebrew to Spanish in Isaiah 14:12?

Why would "Lucero" be applied to the enemy and to Christ?

Comment: 2 Peter 1:19 speaks of the 'day star' (_phosphoros_) arising in the heart. (In Spanish, _el lucero_). It would not be correct to translate _phosphoros_ as 'Christ'. It is a matter of light arising, in connection with, and because of, Christ. The Devil is referred to (in one specific context) as 'an angel of light', 2 Corinthians 11:14, and thus his title is, in certain contexts, 'Lucifer'. (As in Isaiah.) But there are two kinds of light : false light (darkness) and true light.

Comment: You can look at https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/es/Isa%C3%ADas%2014:12 for various Spanish translations and https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Isaiah%2014:12 for various English translations. The word *lucifer* (uncapitalised in the Vulgate but capitalised in the KJV) means *light-bringer* in Latin and was a clear reference to the planet Venus as the morning star.

Answer (score 1):

Lucifer comes from the Latin Vulgate:

> quomodo cecidisti de caelo **lucifer** qui mane oriebaris corruisti in terram qui vulnerabas gentes --
> Biblia Sacra Vulgata: Iuxta Vulgatem Versionem. (1969). (electronic edition of the 3rd edition., Isa. 14:12). Stuttgart: Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft.

The meaning in Latin:

> Lūcĭfer, fēri, m. A. The morning-star, the planet Venus ... --
> Lewis, C. T., & Short, C. (1891). Harpers’ Latin Dictionary (p. 1080). New York; Oxford: Harper & Brothers; Clarendon Press.

In Spanish:

> lucero nm : bright star  --
> Merriam-Webster, I. (1998). Merriam-Webster’s Spanish-English dictionary. Springfield, MA: Merriam-Webster.

Thus, both mean morning star.

They are translating הֵילֵ֣ל

> †הֵילֵל S1966 TWOT499a GK2122 n.m. appell. shining one, epith. of king of Babylon, אֵיךְ נָפַלְתָּ מִשָּׁמַיִם ה׳ בֶּן־שָׁ֑חַר Is 14:12 how art thou fallen, shining one, son of dawn! i.e. star of the morning. (Cf. Assyrian muštilil epith. of (Venus as) morning-star III R 57:60 OppJAS 1871, 448 Schr 1874, 337 COT ad loc.) --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 237). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

The LXX has:

> ἑωσφόρος,-ου      N2M 0-1-1-5-0=7
> 1 Sm 30,17; Is 14,12; Ps 109 (110),3; Jb 3,9; 11,17
> morning star, morning 1 Sm 30,17
> *Ps 109 (110),3 πρὸ ἑωσφόρου before the morning star, before dawn, or before Lucifer-מִשַּׁחַר for MT מִשְׁחָר?
> Cf. TOURNAY 1960, 11–12; →NIDNTT --
> Lust, J., Eynikel, E., & Hauspie, K. (2003). A Greek-English Lexicon of the Septuagint : Revised Edition. Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft: Stuttgart.

2 Peter 1:19 has:

> φωσφόρος, ον bearing or giving light (Eur.+; pap., Philo); subst. ὁ φ. the morning star, Venus (Eur., Ion 1157; Ps.-Pla., Tim. Locr. 96E; 97A; Plut., Mor. 430A; 601A; 889A al.; Cicero, Nat. Deor. 2, 20; Vett. Val. 236, 6; Sib. Or. 5, 516) fig. 2 Pt 1:19. JBoehmer, ZNW 22, ’23, 228-33; FBoll, Sternglaube u. Sterndeutung4 ’31, 47f.—FJDölger, Antike u. Christentum V 1, ’35, 1ff interprets the ‘light-bearer’ to mean the sun (this mng. of φ. in Nicetas Eugen. 1, 87; 3, 21; 5, 258 Hercher); cf. HWindisch ad loc. M-M.* --
> Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur (p. 872). Chicago: University of Chicago Press.

Thus, some take φωσφόρος in 2 Peter 1:19 as meaning Sun instead of morning star. 2 Peter 1:19 does not have the Greek word for morning star that is in Isaiah 14:12.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple answer as both Jesus and Lucifer were referred too as the Morning Star. One Is the most radiant true light and one is the most radiant false light

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).